# JCEF initialization issue on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, chromium-embedded

My Java app which uses JCEF, works perfectly fine in Windows Operating System. But when I try to run this sample application on MacOS Mojave, then it's facing initialization issues. I have added the desired jars and JCEF MacOS libraries/binaries into my project, also added JVM parameter to startup configuration as:
-Djava.library.path=*/jcef/jcef_build/native/Release,
but at the time of running application im facing the folowing error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /jcef_build/native/Release/libjcef.dylib: dlopen(*/jcef_build/native/Release/libjcef.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/Frameworks/Chromium Embedded Framework.framework/Chromium Embedded Framework

Referenced from: */jcef_build/native/Release/libjcef.dylib

Reason: image not found

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at org.cef.CefApp.<init>(CefApp.java:149)
at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:237)
at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:224)
at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:70)
at MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:145)
```

Please any one suggest what I am missing in running this sample application.